# Decryption code not changing actual data

Tags: java, encryption

I am having issues running my code correctly. I created a decryption method that is supposed to take a word and replace every 2 letters with each other. Unless the word is an odd amount, then I should leave the last letter alone. The issue is that I am only printing out the letters and not changing the actual data of the string.

```
static String ezDecrypt (String ezEncrypt){

    //this variable holds the value of the String's length
    int cl = ezEncrypt() ;

    //if the length of the String is even then do this
    if (ezEncrypt.length() % 2 == 0){

        //for loop that begins at 0
        //keeps looping until it reaches the end of the string
        //each loop adds 2 to the loop
        for(int i = 0; i < cl; i= i + 2) {
            //will print out the second letter in the string
            System.out.print(ezEncrypt.charAt(i + 1));
            //will print out the first letter in the string 
            System.out.print(ezEncrypt.charAt(i));             
        }
    }
    //if the length of the word is an odd number, then 
    else if(ezEncrypt.length() % 2 != 0){
        //loop through and do the same process as above
        //except leave this loop will skip the last letter
        for(int i = 0; i < cl-1; i= i + 2) {
            //will print out the second letter in the string
            System.out.print(ezEncrypt.charAt(i + 1));
            //will print out the first letter in the string 
            System.out.print(ezEncrypt.charAt(i));  
        }
    }
    return ezEncrypt;

}
```

Comment: Not that it's wrong, I just don't get `ezEncrypt()`.  Why not call `ezEncrypt.length()` and use `c1` throughout?

Comment: " The issue is that I am only printing out the letters and not changing the actual data of the string." What do you mean? That's the assignment, right? This is transposition, other techniques may follow.

Comment: Yes, you aren't changing letters (or modifying the `String` in any way). So what exactly is the question?

Comment: The purpose of this method is to take a String and swap the letters. I want to be able to call the String after and have it be swapped. Right now I am not actually altering any data. Does this make more sense?

Comment: That still isn't a (valid) question - what problems do you have with writing code that modifies the string? Or creating a new string with the letters in the order you want

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I understand you're trying to modify a String in order to decrypt it. Well, I got some news for you: the `String` class in java has been designed in such a way `String` objects are immutable. That means you can't alter their contents once you have created them. But don't worry, there are other ways to achieve what you have in mind.

For instance, you can get an array of chars from the received object by calling `ezEncrypt.toCharArray()`; you can modify the contents of an array so you will have to work with that, swapping the characters just like you're supposed to. Then, once the decryption is done, create another `String` object by using the constructor `new String(char[] chars)`, passing your array as argument, and return it.

Something more or less like this:

```java
static String ezDecrypt (String ezEncrypt){
    //this variable holds the value of the String's length
    int cl = ezEncrypt.length();

    //an array holding each character of the originally received text
    char[] chars = ezEncrypt.toCharArray();

    //temporary space for a lonely character
    char tempChar;

    //Do your swapping here
    if (ezEncrypt.length() % 2 == 0){ //Length is even
        //for loop that begins at 0
        //keeps looping until it reaches the end of the string
        //each loop adds 2 to the loop
        for(int i = 0; i < cl; i = i + 2) {
            tempChar = chars[i];
            chars[i] = chars[i+1];
            chars[i+1] = tempChar;
        }
    } else { //Length is odd
        //loop through and do the same process as above
        //except leave this loop will skip the last letter
        for(int i = 0; i < cl - 1; i = i + 2) {
            tempChar = chars[i];
            chars[i] = chars[i+1];
            chars[i+1] = tempChar;
        }
    }
    return new String(chars);
}
```

Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 1):

Strings are immutable, so calling a method on the string will not change the string. It will only return a value derived from the string. You need to make a new empty string and start adding the return values to it character by character.

Comment: Empty strings are immutable too. You should rather advise to use a StringBuilder instead. Because that is what the compiler inserts for you any time you use the string + operator.

Comment: Yes string builder would be a good option too. Empty strings are immutable. But when you use the + operator you can still assign to the same variable...and the code is arguably cleaner looking.